# Growing a list in haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm learning Haskell by writing an OSC musical sequencer to use it with SuperCollider. But because I'd like to make fairly complex stuff with it, it will work like a programming language where you can declare variables and define functions so you can write music in an algorithmic way. The grammar is unusual in that we're coding sequences and sometimes a bar will reference the last bar (something like "play that last chord again but a fifth above").
I don't feel satisfied with my own explanation, but that's the best I can without getting too technical.

Anyway, what I'm coding now is the parser for that language, stateless so far, but now I need some way to implement a growing list of the declared variables and alikes using a dictionary in the `[("key","value")]` fashion, so I can add new values as I go parsing bar by bar. 
I know this involves monads, which I don't really understand yet, but I need something meaningful enough to start toying with them or else I find the raw theory a bit too raw.

So what would be a clean and simple way to start?
Thanks and sorry if the question was too long.

Edit on how the thing works:

- we input a string to the main parsing function, say
  `"afunction(3)  ; anotherone(1) + [3,2,1]"`
- we identify closures first, then kinds of chars (letters, nums, etc) and group them together, so we get a list like:
  `[("word","afunction"),("parenth","(3)"),("space","  "),("semicolon",";"),("space"," "),("word","anotherone"),("parenth","(1)"),("space"," "),("opadd","+"),("space"," "),("bracket","[3,2,1]")]`
- then we use a function that tags all those tuples with the indices of the original string they occupy, like:
  `[("word","afunction",(0,8)),("parenth","(3)",(9,11)),("space","  ",(12,13)) ...]`
- then cut it in a list of bars, which in my language are separated using a semicolon, and then in notes, using commas.

And now I'm at the stage where those functions should be executed sequentially, but because some of them are reading or modifying previously declared values, I need to keep track of that change. For example, let's say the function `f(x)` moves the pitch of the last note by `x` semitones, so

```
f(9), -- from an original base value of 0 (say that's an A440) we go to 9
f(-2), -- 9-2 = 7, so a fifth from A
f(-3); -- 9-2-3, a minor third down from the last value.
```

etc

But sometimes it can get a bit more complicated than that, don't make me explain how cause I could bore you to death.

Comment: Are you using parsec or some other parsing framework for your parser, or are you hand-rolling it?  Can you post an example of how your parser is structured so we can make a good recommendation?

Comment: Without additional details about your attempt so far, I'm afraid that this question may be too broad for Stack Overflow...

Comment: Seems like comments can't be too long, I'll edit the main post.

Comment: @AsíMaullóJosetustra That's the way to go.

Comment: @AsíMaullóJosetustra A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code.

Comment: "list of the declared variables and alikes using a dictionary in the [("key","value")] fashion" - seriously, don't do this.  `Data.Map` is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Adding an item to a list

You can make a new list that contains one more item than an existing list with the `:` constructor.

```
("key", "value") : existing
```

Where `existing` is a list you've already made

#### Keeping track of changing state

You can keep track of changing state between functions by passing the state from each function to the next. This is all the [`State`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:State) monad is doing. `State s a` is a value of type `a` that depends on (and changes) a state `s`.

```
{-         ┌---- type of the state
           v v-- type of the value                 -}
data State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
{-                                   ^  ^  ^  ^
      a function                  ---|--┘  |  |
      that takes a state          ---┘     |  |
      and returns                          |  |
      a value that depends on the state ---┘  |
      and a new state                   ------┘    -}
```

The bind operation `>>=` for `State` takes a value that depends on (and changes) the state and a function to compute another value that depends on (and changes) the state and combines them to make a new value that depends on (and changes) the state.

```
m >>= k = State $ \s ->
              let ~(a, s') = runState m s
              in runState (k a) s'
```

Comment: Aren't let patterns always lazy?

Comment: This is probably what I was looking for although I don't know how to implement it yet,  I'll read some tutorials about it.
 I don't have reputation enough to upvote you, but I feel compelled to thank you.